# Firestore value returns only one value

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, google-cloud-firestore

whenever I try to retrieve data from firestore,only one part is called
You can see that I have a ListTile with a title and a Subtitle
Now only the data in the subtitle is being displayed and it requires no null indication
But the title requires the null indication but still it does not returns the string [This is my firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuGcu.png)

Thank You

```dart
// ...

class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  Future<QuerySnapshot> searchResultsFuture;

  handleSearch(String query){
    Future<QuerySnapshot> users = usersReference.where("profilename",isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query ).getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      searchResultsFuture = users;
    });
  //searchResultsFuture = users;
  }

  clearSearch(){
    searchController.clear();
  }

  AppBar buildSearchField(){
      return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: TextFormField(
          controller: searchController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Search Your Friends",
            filled: true,
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.account_box,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: clearSearch,
            ),
          ),
          onFieldSubmitted: handleSearch,
        ),
      );
  }

  Container buildNoContent(){
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.group, color: Colors.white,size: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 400.0 : 200.0 ,),
          Text("Find Users",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontSize: 65.0),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildSearchResults() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: searchResultsFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return circularProgress();
          }
          List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc){
            User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
            UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
            searchResults.add(searchResult);
          });
          return ListView(
            children: searchResults,
          );
        }
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.8) ,
      appBar: buildSearchField(),
      body: searchResultsFuture == null ? buildNoContent() : buildSearchResults(),
    );
  }
}


class UserResult extends StatelessWidget {

  final User eachUser;

  UserResult(this.eachUser);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.7),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: ()=> print("tapped"),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(eachUser.url),
            ),
            title: eachUser.profileName != null ? Text(eachUser.profileName,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),): 'User',
            subtitle: Text(eachUser.username,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          ),
        ),
        Divider(
          height: 2.0,
          color: Colors.white54,
        ),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the code snippet to publish your codes. It is unstructured.

Comment: I have updated my code,please take a look

Answer (score 0):

try uploading a more detailed code so as to get insights of what might be wrong.

I thinnk you shoud try to call setSate in

```
void didChangeDependencies() {
super.didChangeDependencies();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((callback) async {
  /// logic here!
  eachUser = get data from firebase;
  after that call setState();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the proplem is:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> users = usersReference.where("profilename",isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query ).getDocuments();
setState(() {
  searchResultsFuture = users;
});
```

searchResultsFuture get value when users hadn't completed

Comment: What should I do then?